# Adds a stopwatch to a presentation in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to show a stopwatch on my presentation (in all slides) in PowerPoint. The timer is not only for the presenter, but also for the viewers.
His role is to mark when the presentation should end.

Do you know a way to do this?

A solution that includes code will also be accepted.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done prior to asking this question here? Right now it appears you're asking us to write code for you, but SuperUser isn't a code-writing service. We're members of a community that helps you solve your problems.

Comment: Is this a count-up timer, or a count-down timer?

Comment: @music2myear I searched Google of course, and saw a lot of techniques, but they all work on one slide only. I guess the solution will require code. I did not ask for full code, just an example of cross-slide counting, and updating cross-slide text.

Comment: @music2myear It count-down, but I do not think it matters.

Comment: A "stop watch" typically measures the time it takes to complete an event and is therefore a "count-up" clock. A timer typically communicates a constraining amount of time, and therefore is a "count-down" clock. The words you use matter for the accurate communication of your actual request. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear what you ask. Also, what have you tried. In an internet search I found several options for inserting various forms of time measurement into a presentation. Knowing what you've already tried will save us from duplicating your work and wasting your time.

Comment: @music2myear It does not matter which way he counts, if I'm not looking for a complete solution.And you also said that there is no complete solution here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real time countdown on powerpoint slides](https://superuser.com/questions/1078395/real-time-countdown-on-powerpoint-slides).  This might also be helpful: [How/ Can I have a countdown timer/ stopwatch in a PDF?](https://superuser.com/q/845012/364367)